# TCP/IP basics: Destination port relevance

Tags: linux, network-programming, linux-kernel, tcpclient

Ok this is kind of embarassing but I just have a rather "noob" question.

In a client server TCP communications, where my system is a client accessing a remote server at say Port XX, isnt the client opening a random port YY in its system to talk to remote port XX?
So when we code we do specify the destination port XX right?

For the client, the port YY itself is chosen when the socket is created, isnt it?

Is there anyway I could monitor/restrict/control any client talking to a particular server?(like say clients talking to servers at specific serving ports??)

Is there any IPTABLE rule or some firewall rule restricting the client?
Can this be done at all??

Are destination ports saved in the socket structures? If so where??

Thanks!

Comment: by the way, client may explicitly specify it's port, so client's port not _always_ random.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, server side creates a *listening socket*, with the chain of [`socket(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html), [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html), and [`listen(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/listen.2.html) calls, then waits for incoming client connection requests with the [`accept(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/accept.2.html) call. Once a client connects ([`socket(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/socket.2.html) and then [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) on the client side) and the TCP/IP stacks of the client and the server machines complete the [*three way handshake*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_handshake#Connection_establishment), the [`accept(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/accept.2.html) returns new socket descriptor - that's the server's end of the *connected socket*. Both [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html) on the server side, and [`connect(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/connect.2.html) on the client side take *server's address and port*.

Now, the full TCP connection is described by four numbers - server address, server port, client address, and client port. The first two must obviously be known to the client prior to the connection attempt (otherwise, where do we go?). The client address and port, while could be specified explicitly with the [`bind(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/bind.2.html), are usually assigned dynamically - the address is the IP address of the outgoing network interface, as determined by the [*routing table*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Routing_table), and the port selected out of range of [*ephemeral ports*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port).

The [`netstat(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/netstat) command shows you established connections. Adding `-a` flag lets you see listening sockets, `-n` flag disables DNS and service resolution, so you just see numeric addresses and ports.

Linux [`iptables(8)`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/iptables) allows you to restrict where clients are allowed to connect to. You can restrict based on source and destination ports, addresses, and more.

You can get socket local binding with [`getsockname(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getsockname.2.html) call, remote binding is given by [`getpeername(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/getpeername.2.html).

Hope this makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: Thanks that was very clear :). +1 for all the names of the different socket routines.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create a firewall rule to prevent outbound TCP connections to port XX. For example, some organizations prevent outbound TCP port 25, to prevent spam being sent from network PCs to remote SMTP servers.

Comment: Thanks JJ. And if I have to programmatically restrict a destination port of a client, s it only possible in the kernel??

Comment: Is there any linux commands to see if to which dest port my client is communicating?

Comment: What do you mean by " programmatically restrict a destination port of a client"? If you are writing the client code you can "try" to connect to any port you choose. A firewall decides whether or not to allow the connection.

Comment: You can use `netstat -at` to view TCP ports in use on the system.

Comment: Yes thanks. I was looking into the net/ipv4 directory of the kernel and looking through the kernel code to see how a socket is created.Therefore wanted to know if somewhere in the kernel code the destination ports and server IPs are checked.